I tweaked some of my Firefox about:config settings, now stackoverflow.com froze because some JS file takes too long to begin downloading
I've just finished my personal Firefox tweaks that taken 5 different user.js as references.
But when I visited stackoverflow.com:

Some of the elements are rendered then froze, I can't click on anything:
initial render

After 2 to 3 seconds then the loading is completed:
finish render


My investigation using DevTools > Network: There are some JS file takes a lot of time to start downloading:

1st delay
2nd delay

Here is my user.js file, I have added a ToC for easier navigation:
https://gist.github.com/Silverbullet069/a4b51d7cfe34ea51853fe71f4f719c2e
Anyone have this same issues after tweaking and found the cause? Please shed some light for me, I can't stand of waiting 3 seconds to read a SOF answer :v

It's the Dark Reader :v I do a Safe Mode reset with user.js applied and everything back to normal => An extension is doing nasty things to my browser.
I changed it v5 and let it auto-detect dark mode on-site and disable itself if found.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
